# Android - how to add new data to exiting unique key in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add new data for child node that named "unique key" from "pibref.push().getkey". When I try to sign in first it works perfectly.
[pic : my "dll dll" data inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWfN6.png),
 but if I restart my app I get an error like this :

```
07-05 11:14:46.341 11765-11765/com.rintan.geistr.pib W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
07-05 11:14:46.346 11765-11765/com.rintan.geistr.pib W/System.err:     at com.rintan.geistr.pib.transfer.vdigital(transfer.java:161)
```

.

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    View.OnClickListener {
...
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    ...
    ...
    pibref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    String key = pibref.push().getKey();

    Users = pibref.child(key); 
}
public static DatabaseReference userkey(){
    DatabaseReference userr = new SignInActivity().Users;
    return userr;
}
```

transfer.java

```
DatabaseReference UserKey = SignInActivity.userkey();
pibref_userkirim = UserKey.child("User_Transaksi");   //this is line 161
usr_tf = pibref_userkirim.child("Transfer");
usr_tf.child(stremailterima).setValue(transkirim);
```

Help me please ... this is my semester project :'(

Comment: Setting the `Users` property is very verbose in your code. Why not use `Users = pibref.push();` as `push()` returns a DatabaseReference?

Comment: Where are you displaying your data. Can you share us same code?

Comment: @samthecodingman : i've tried it but it asked me to convert Users to string not as database references and will return null database reference

Comment: @AlexMamo : did u mean an intrface for displaying data ? i have not displaying my data yet

Comment: @EstrelaSteign: But that makes no sense. What type is `Users`? Is it a `String`, `Class` or `DatabaseReference`?. Your code is ambiguous because `pibref.child('someString')` will return a `DatabaseReference`. If you use `String key = pibref.push().getKey();` to get the new key's id, and then instantly use `Users = pibref.child(key);`, then `Users = pibref.push()` should work just fine. Furthermore, `new SignInActivity().Users` should be `(new SignInActivity()).Users` for clarity.

Comment: @samthecodingman i know thats big mistakes. yeah, i've edited my code. named node with getUid user g+ and convert user Uid as database references and it works :D   .

Comment: @EstrelaSteign So which part fixed it? If it's something I mentioned then I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: @samthecodingman nope :D. i'm not use "String key = pibref.push().getKey(); .... ... .. ..". i've changed my node name with Uid

Answer (score 0):

Inside your override method of onComplete listenre do the following:

```
User user=new User();
user.setFirstName(firstname);
user.setLastname(lastname);

  mDatabase.child("UserNode").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(user, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
  @Override
   public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
      if(databaseError==null)
          {
              Log.e("final value", "Data is saved successfully");
          }
                 }
                   });
```

declare this line on the top:

```
 private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
```

Hope it helps